# Would the ability to declare Lisp functions 'pure' be beneficial?

Tags: lisp, computer-science, compiler-optimization, proof, purely-functional

I have been reading a lot about [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/) lately, and the benefits that it derives from being a *purely* functional language.  (I'm not interested in discussing monads for Lisp)  It makes sense to me to (at least logically) isolate functions with side-effects as much as possible.  I have used `setf` and other destructive functions plenty, and I recognize the need for them in Lisp and (most of) its derivatives.

Here we go:

1. Would something like `(declare pure)` potentially help an optimizing compiler?  Or is this a moot point because it already knows?
2. Would the declaration help in proving a function or program, or at least a subset that was declared as pure?  Or is this again something that is unnecessary because it's already obvious to the programmer and compiler and prover?
3. If for nothing else, would it be useful to a programmer for the compiler to enforce purity for functions with this declaration and add to the readability/maintainablity of Lisp programs?
4. Does any of this make any sense?  Or am I too tired to even think right now?

I'd appreciate any insights here.  Info on compiler implementation or provability is welcome.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I didn't intend to restrict this question to Common Lisp.  It clearly (I think) doesn't apply to certain derivative languages, but I'm also curious if some features of other Lisps may tend to support (or not) this kind of facility.

Comment: I am neither a Haskel nor a Lisp expert, but I know a bit of both: I think a mechanism for enforcing purity in Lisp would be an advantage. I was even surprised to learn that Lisp allows side-effects in the first place. I am curious to read answers to this question given by experts.

Comment: @Giorgio I am eagerly awaiting an outpouring of pure nerdy goodness.  Scheme was taught in my first CS class, and we were sheltered from the evil `!`...I thought for years that the main difference between CL and Scheme was purity...then all my hopes and dreams were crushed when I learned how to read the interwebs.

Comment: Is scheme pure? By the way, you might want to also check Clean out. It has yet another mechanism to deal with side-effects in a clean way (http://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean).

Comment: It's decidedly impure, but really nice in some ways compared to CL.  Wow, looked at that link, looks like someone copied a page about Haskell and did a query-replace with 'Clean'.

Comment: They are indeed similar: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.functional/msg/c09cb40a66558a19

Comment: I think this question would fit better on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @Tom Considered that briefly but am convinced that this is way more about implementation than theory...but I'm sure I'll learn some from this question.  Plus a quick scan of the topics over there is downright scary.

Comment: Ha...maybe I was wrong on that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two answers but neither touch on the real problem.

First, yes, it would obviously be good to know that a function is pure.  There's a ton of compiler level things that would like to know that, as well as user level things.  Given that lisp languages are so flexible, you could twist things a bit: instead of a "pure" declaration that asks the compiler to try harder or something, you just make the declaration *restrict* the code  in the definition.  This way you can guarantee that the function is pure.

You can even do that with additional supporting facilities -- I mentioned two of them in a comment I made to johanbev's answer: add the notion of immutable bindings and immutable data structures.  I know that in *Common* Lisp these are very problematic, especially immutable bindings (since CL loads code by "side-effecting" it into place).   But such features will help simplifying things, and they're not inconceivable (see for example the [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) implementation that has immutable pairs and other data structures, and has immutable bindings.

But the real question is what can you do in such restricted functions.  Even a very simple looking problem would be infested with issues.  (I'm using Scheme-like syntax for this.)

```
(define-pure (foo x)
  (cons (+ x 1) (bar)))
```

Seems easy enough to tell that this function is indeed pure, it doesn't do anything .  Also, seems that having `define-pure` restrict the body and allow only pure code would work fine in this case, and will allow this definition.

Now start with the problems:

1. It's calling `cons`, so it assumes that it is also known to be pure.  In addition, as I mentioned above, it should rely on `cons` being what it is, so assume that the `cons` binding is immutable.  Easy, since it's a known builtin.  Do the same with `bar`, of course.
2. But `cons` *does* have a side effect (even if you're talking about Racket's immutable pairs): it *allocates* a new pair.  This seems like a minor and ignorable point, but, for example, if you allow such things to appear in pure functions, then you won't be able to auto-memoize them.  The problem is that someone might rely on every `foo` call returning a new pair -- one that is not-`eq` to any other existing pair.  Seems that to make it fine you need to further restrict pure functions to deal not only with immutable values, but also values where the constructor doesn't always create a new value (eg, it could hash-cons instead of allocate).
3. But that code also calls `bar` -- so no you need to make the same assumptions on `bar`: it must be known as a pure function, with an immutable binding.  Note specifically that `bar` receives no arguments -- so in that case the compiler could not only require that `bar` is a pure function, it could also use that information and pre-compute its value.  After all, a pure function with no inputs could be reduced to a plain value.  (Note BTW that Haskell doesn't have zero-argument functions.)
4. And that brings another big issue in.  What if `bar` is a function of *one* input?  In that case you'd have an error, and some exception will get thrown ... and that's no longer pure.  Exceptions are side-effects.  You now need to know the arity of `bar` in addition to everything else, and you need to avoid other exceptions.  Now, how about that input `x` -- what happens if it isn't a number?  That will throw an exception too, so you need to avoid it too.  This means that you now need a type system.
5. Change that `(+ x 1)` to `(/ 1 x)` and you can see that not only do you need a type system, you need one that is sophisticated enough to distinguish 0s.
6. Alternatively, you could re-think the whole thing and have new pure arithmetic operations that never throw exceptions -- but with all the other restrictions you're now quite a long way from home, with a language that is radically different.
7. Finally, there's one more side-effect that remains a PITA: what if the definition of `bar` is `(define-pure (bar) (bar))`?  It certainly is pure according to all of the above restrictions...  But diverging is a form of a side effect, so even this is no longer kosher.  (For example, if you did make your compiler optimize nullary functions to values, then for this example the compiler itself would get stuck in an infinite loop.)  (And yes, Haskell doesn't deal with that, it doesn't make it less of an issue.)

Comment: Restricting the function via the declaration was what I was really getting at, I just worded the question poorly, and a declaration seems clunky in retrospect. Your points make me question the absolute purity of the "purely" functional languages. It's kinda like the Heisenberg uncertainty principle in my mind; a language can be fully pure or fully work, but never both at the same time.

Comment: For #7, would it not make sense for `define-pure` to barf on a nullary lambda?  I realize that you gave an uber-simple example of a divergent function (which btw seems easy to catch...correct me if I'm wrong) but is trickier divergence of a supposedly pure function decidable at compile-time?

Comment: Yeah, getting a really pure language to work is a challenge.  Haskell is doing a considerable effort, but there are still plenty of issues left.  As for the nullary version -- that would be one solution, I just wanted to highlight the issue.

Comment: I mean, if you're gonna hafta relax somewhere in a dynamically typed language, it seems like runtime exceptions could be allowed as a partial workaround...We'll just make our pure Lisp code rewrite itself to be more pure until it magically becomes self-aware.  By the way, is anyone else a little disappointed that only a couple of people have anything to say on the topic?

Comment: You were talking about benefits in a(n optimizing) compiler -- that's an area where you can't just "work around" things.  Just take the obvious optimization of folding an all constant expression like `(foo 3)`: if exceptions can happen then now your compiler can break.  Yes, you can iron over this, but such problems will continue to happen.  (By the way, this is a hard question.)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it has been the most instructive.  However, I appreciate everyone's input.  In hindsight, this question was probably way too open-ended and maybe should have gone on cs.SE.  Wasn't intentional...I understood the implications even less when I asked it, and learned a lot.  Thanks to all who provided input.

Answer (score 3):

Given a Lisp function, knowing if it is pure or not is undecidable in general. Of course, necessary conditions and sufficient conditions can be tested at compile time. (If there are no impure operations at all, then the function must be pure; if an impure operation gets executed unconditionally, then the function must be impure; for more complicated cases, the compiler could try to prove that the function is pure or impure, but it will not succeed in all cases.)

1. If the user can manually annotate a function as pure, then the compiler could either (a.) try harder to prove that the function is pure, ie. spend more time before giving up, or (b.) assume that it is and add optimizations which would not be correct for impure functions (like, say, memoizing results). So, yes, annotating functions as pure could help the compiler if the annotations are assumed to be correct.
2. Apart from heuristics like the "trying harder" idea above, the annotation would not help to prove stuff, because it's not giving any information to the prover. (In other words, the prover could just assume that the annotation is always there before trying.) However, it could make sense to attach to pure functions a *proof* of their purity.
3. The compiler could either (a.) check if pure functions are indeed pure at compile time, but this is undecidable in general, or (b.) add code to try to catch side effects in pure functions at runtime and report those as an error. (a.) would probably be helpful with simple heuristics (like "an impure operation gets executed unconditionally), (b.) would be useful for debug.
4. No, it seems to make sense. Hopefully this answer also does.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I hadn't thought about verifying purity being so difficult...is the problem intractable even when limiting the 'pure' functions to a subset of Lisp + pure-proven functions?  I'm curious how inclusion macros or not in some variants of Lisp would affect the difficulty of the problem. When I read your answer (still tired)    it occurred to me that `progn` and relatives would complicate things, and with all the implicit `progn`s everywhere, it's a downhill slope.  Would a new special form potentially be able to enforce purity?  A proof of purity as metadata would be cool.

Comment: Verifying purity is, in general, undecidable: is `(if (undecidable-function user-input) (do-something-impure))` pure or not?  And even to get to the point where you can decide that that's undecidable, you need to decide whether or not `undecidable-function` is undecidable after all...

Answer (score 1):

The usual goodies apply when we can assume purity and referential
transparency. We can automatically memoize hotspots. We can
automatically parallelize computation. We can deal away with a lot of
race conditions. We can also use structure sharing with data that we
know cannot be modified, for instance the (quasi) primitive ``cons()''
does not need to copy the cons-cells in the list it's consing to.
These cells are not affected in any way by having another cons-cell
pointing to it. This example is kinda obvious, but compilers are often
good performers in figuring out more complex structure sharing.

However, actually determining if a lambda (a function) is pure or has
referential transparency is very tricky in Common Lisp. Remember that
a funcall (foo bar) start by looking at (symbol-function foo). So in
this case

```
(defun foo (bar)
  (cons 'zot bar))
```

foo() is pure.

The next lambda is also pure.

```
(defun quux ()
 (mapcar #'foo '(zong ding flop)))
```

However, later on we can redefine foo:

```
(let ((accu -1))
 (defun foo (bar)
   (incf accu)))
```

The next call to quux() is no longer pure! The old pure foo() has been
redefined to an impure lambda. Yikes. This example is maybe somewhat
contrived but it's not that uncommon to lexically redefine some
functions, for instance with a let block. In that case it's not
possible to know what would happen at compile time.

Common Lisp has a very dynamic semantic, so actually being
able to determine control flow and data flow ahead of time (for
instance when compiling) is very hard, and in most useful cases
entirely undecidable. This is quite typical of languages with dynamic
type systems. There is a lot of common idioms in Lisp you cannot use
if you must use static typing. It's mainly these that fouls any
attempt to do much meaningful static analysis.  We can do it for primitives
like cons and friends. But for lambdas involving other things than
primitives we are in much deeper water, especially in the cases where
we need to look at complex interplay between functions. Remember that
a lambda is only pure if all the lambdas it calls are also pure.

On the top of my head, it could be possible, with some deep macrology,
to do away with the redefinition problem. In a sense, each lambda gets
an extra argument which is a monad that represents the entire state of
the lisp image (we can obviously restrict ourselves to what the function
will actually look at). But it's probably more useful to be able do
declare purity ourselves, in the sense that we promise the compiler
that this lambda is indeed pure. The consequences if it isn't is then
undefined, and all sorts of mayhem could ensue...

Comment: I would think that running at compile-time would be something that a Lisp would be better suited for that most languages...

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The first `cons` example is not pure in the sense that you're talking about -- that belongs elsewhere, as a constructor for immutable pairs.  You're also wrong in your later example with `#'foo` -- that is also easy to resolve by enforcing that any "pure" binding is immutable, and its body can refer only to other immutable functions.

Comment: @Eli, im not saying that it's impossible, but I was talking about "vanilla" Common Lisp. Of course you can design a pure sublanguage in it... But I do believe that my arguments hold for normal unmodified run of the mill common lisp.

Im not sure what you mean about the cons()-example, it will put zot as the head of the cons cell in bar anytime. If you call it with the same bar, you will get the same result. Also, bar isn't destroyed in the process. Perhaps im being vauge.

Comment: A function that is guaranteed to cons cannot be considered pure, for example memoizing would not be allowed (imagine someone calling the function, then modifying the cons cell it got, and then someone else calling the function with the same parameters... returning the same memoized cons cell - that now has been modified - is of course wrong).